# Tensorflow - how to use same dropout mask at each row

Tags: tensorflow

How can I use `tf.nn.dropout` to apply the same dropout mask to each row of a tensor?

Example:

I have a 3D tensor of shape `(2,2,3)`:

```
[[[  1.   2.   3.]
  [  4.   5.   6.]]

 [[  7.   8.   9.]
  [ 10.  11.  12.]]]
```

When using dropout, the same mask should be applied to each row. Also, when an entry is dropped out, all elements of the third dimension should be set to zero. 
Let's say that in each row/horizontal slize, only the second entry is dropped out, corresponding to a dropout mask of `[1,0]` per row. This should give (not including the rescaling of the other entries):

```
[[[  1.   2.   3.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  7.   8.   9.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]
```

By providing a `noise_shape` to `tf.nn.dropout` I can make sure, that all elements in the third dimension are set to zero. This can be done using `noise_shape=[2,2,1]`. However, I don't know how I can ensure that the same dropout mask is used for each row/slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone stumbles over this question in the future, I will post the answer myself. The behavior can be achieved by providing `noise_shape=[1,2,1]` to `tf.nn.dropout`. Or in general, when having a tensor of shape `(m,n,e)` setting `noise_shape=[1,n,1]`